# How can I write R ggplot charts into palantir foundry file system?

Tags: cloud-foundry, palantir-foundry

looking for a way to use foundry code repository to write a visualisation created via an R-Script using ggplot2 into the foundry file system.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  This is answered in the documentation here: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/transforms-unstructured/#example-saving-a-plot-to-a-pdf
It is possible to write to an output FileSystem. This can be useful to write non-tabular data formats including images, PDFs, text files, and so on.

Call new.output() to instantiate a TransformOutput. [Learn more about the FileSystem API.](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-workbook/r-filesystem/)

You can only write files using TransformOutput in nodes that are saved as datasets. You cannot write files using TransformOutput in the console.

Here is an example with a scatterplot (saved to a PDF to maintain good resolution):

```
plot_pdf <- function() {
    library(ggplot2)
    theme_set(theme_bw())  # pre-set the bw theme
    data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")

    # Scatterplot
    gg <- ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + 
        geom_point(aes(col=state, size=popdensity)) + 
        geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
        xlim(c(0, 0.1)) + 
        ylim(c(0, 500000)) + 
        labs(subtitle="Area Vs Population", 
            y="Population", 
            x="Area", 
            title="Scatterplot", 
            caption = "Source: midwest")
            
    output <- new.output()
    output_fs <- output$fileSystem()
    pdf(output_fs$get_path("my pdf example.pdf", 'w'))
    plot(gg)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it means there is no way writing ggplot 2 chart using code repository?

Comment: It would be the same.  You use the `TransformOutput` to write the ggplot2 chart as a pdf using code repository.